# Mac Addressbook to mySQL via AppleScript

Tags: mysql, applescript

Does anyone know a way to export addressbook contents to mySQL DB via AppleScript?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or are you at least able to start off on some code? If so, do post it so that perhaps it can be worked on from there..

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Address Book database is just an SQLite database. Maybe rather than trying to do this via AppleScript, you should be looking for something that will convert an SQLite database into MySQL.

To get started, export a (.abbu) backup from Address Book. Right click on the backup file and "Show Package Contents". In there will be a file named "Address Book-vXX.abcddb". This is the SQLite file you should be working on.

You can use something like [Base](http://menial.co.uk/software/base/) to read that SQLite file, and look at the data and schema.